# How can I read a paragraph in via the terminal as a single string in C?

Tags: c, string, scanf

I'm writing a C program that should read in an essay from a user.  The essay is divided into multiple paragraphs.
I don't know how many lines or characters the essay will be, but I do know that it ends with a hash symbol (`#`).  I want to use only as much memory as is necessary to hold the essay.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


main(){

    int size;
    char *essay;

    printf("\n how many characters?\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    essay =(char *) malloc(size+1);
    printf("Type the string\n");
    scanf("%s",essay);

    printf("%s",essay );

}
```

As I said before, I don't know (and don't want to ask) about the number of characters beforehand.  How do I dynamically allocate memory to save space? (What is dynamic memory allocation?) Is there another way to save memory that doesn't rely on dynamic allocation?

Additionally, my code only reads one line at a time right now.  How can I read multiple lines and store them as a single string?

this is another code

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    
int main ()
{
  char input;
  int count = 0;
int n;
  char* characters= NULL;
  char* more_characters = NULL;
  do {
     printf ("type the essay:\n");
     scanf ("%d", &input);
     count++;

       more_characters = (char*) realloc (characters, count * sizeof(char));
      if (more_characters!=NULL) {
       characters=more_characters;
       characters[count-1]=input;  }
     else {
       free (characters);
       printf ("Error (re)allocating memory");
       exit (1);
     }
  } while (input!='#');

printf ("the essay: ");
    for (n=0;n<count;n++) printf ("%c",characters[n]);
    free (characters);
   }
```

it is not working

Comment: "is there another way to save the space of memory?" Compression. Which I really can't recommend as a technique until you're fully familiar with dynamic allocation. "how can i read multiple lines and store it in a single string ?" If you're willing to trade simplicity for poor performance in the long run: use [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc).

Comment: "my code just read one line "  __> I disagree, it reads one word as any space will stop further reading.

Comment: use [getdelim](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getdelim)

Comment: Note: `more_characters = (char*) realloc (characters, count * sizeof(char));` can be simplified to `more_characters = realloc(characters, count);`

Answer (score 1):

You can read character at a time and copy it into your essay buffer. When your essay buffer runs out of space, you can do a realloc to get another chunk of memory.  When your character that you read is a "#" you're done.

Comment: what is the buffer .I only know how to read from user by use scanf

Comment: You can use getc to read a char at a time.  It is still using buffered IO.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm to "not waste space in memory",

then how about excessive calls of `realloc()`?

```
char *Read_Paragraph_i(void) {
  size_t size = 0;
  size_t i = 0;
  char *dest = NULL; 
  int ch;
  while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
    if (ch == '#') break;
    size++;
    char *new_ptr = realloc(dest, size);
    assert(new_ptr);
    dest = new_ptr;
    dest[i++] = ch;
  }
  size++;
  char *new_ptr = realloc(dest, size+);
  assert(new_ptr);
  dest = new_ptr;
  dest[i++] = '\0';
  return dest;
}
```

A more sane approach would double the allocation size every time more memory is need, temporally wasting memory and then a final "right-size" allocation.

Comment: there are alot of function we do not study it is there another way can i use scanf or gets() or any basic function? also what is the data type siz_t

Comment: @user5517410 If the answer needs limitations, list the limitations in the post.

Answer (score 0):

If this can use C++, you can use string (std::string) which will grow as needed as characters are added.  If you can't then you will have to use malloc to create an array to hold characters.  When it is full, you will have to create a new one, and copy the current data from old to new one, then add the new character.  You can do that on each character read to use the minimal amount of memory, but that is WAY too inefficient.  A better way is to allocate the character array in chucks, keeping the current size, and the number of characters currently in it.  When you want to add another character and the array is full, then you allocate a new one that is some number of characters larger than current one, update current size to size of new one, then add new character.

Comment: or like @bruceg said, use realloc to create the new buffer, as it will do the copy for you.

Comment: @user5517410 not sure if you down-voted it, but I did provide a solution in C